My jenkins pipeline was working fine and now all of a sudden it stops right away after I click build and trigger it. Putting all the logs here below
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:18 PM INFO hudson.WebAppMain contextInitialized
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:18 PM INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
Started w.@76318a7d{Jenkins v2.462.3,/,file:///var/cache/jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/cache/jenkins/war}
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:18 PM INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
Started ServerConnector@12405818{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:18 PM INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
Started Server@1a38c59b{STARTING}[10.0.24,sto=0] @1397ms
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:18 PM INFO winstone.Logger logInternal
Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:18 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Started initialization
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:18 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Listed all plugins
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:22 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Prepared all plugins
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:22 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Started all plugins
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:22 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Augmented all extensions
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:22 PM INFO hudson.plugins.build_timeout.global.GlobalTimeOutConfiguration load
global timeout not set
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:23 PM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl
Docker URL is not set, docker client won't be initialized
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:24 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
System config loaded
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:24 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
System config adapted
Nov 18, 2024 4:54:24 PM WARNING io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config getExecCredentialFromExecConfig
sh: 1: oci: not found

Nov 18, 2024 4:54:24 PM WARNING io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config getExecCredentialFromExecConfig
Error unmarshalling ExecCredential
mapping values are not allowed here
in reader, line 1, column 6:
sh: 1: oci: not found

#This is the log. I got it from Manage Jenkins > All System logs.
#oci and kubectl is already configured in my jenkins server. It can be accessed  from anywhere in the server

The question description is a bit unclear. Please expand the question title in the description.

Have you been editing any YAML files associated with that job or on the host of the Jenkins? This error occurs only if a YAML config file is configured improperly. 
"This YAML error is typically caused by incorrect indentation or nesting of data structures. YAML relies on indentation to denote structure and relationships."
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-do-i-resolve-a-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-here-error-in-yaml/
